# how to count the times it appears the same string in a diccionary

Tags: python

I am trying to code an "election". When the user first has to put how many votes are going to be, and then write every candidate they want. This is what i did so far.

```
def election():

  results = {
      
  }

  number = int(input("Number of votes: "))
  n = 0 
  
  
  while n < number:

    vote = input("Choose your candidate: ")
    results[n] = vote
    n = n + 1
      
  else:
    print(results)  
      
    
election()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 'print' use 'return' in the function so you will be able to work with the output.

```
  results = {
      
  }

  number = int(input("Number of votes: "))
  n = 0 
  
  
  while n < number:

    vote = input("Choose your candidate: ")
    results[n] = vote
    n = n + 1
      
  else:
    return results 
      
    
x = election()
```

Using the Counter class you would obtain a dictionary showing the number of times the same string appears in your dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more method for counting the frequency of "candidate" in dictionary:

```
def count_votes(results):
  dictresult = {}
  for v in results.values():
     if v not in dictresult:
        dictresult[v] = 1
    else:
        dictresult[v] += 1
print(dictresult)



def election():
  results = {}
  number = int(input("Number of votes: "))
  n = 0 
  while n < number:
    vote = input("Choose your candidate: ")
    results[n] = vote
    n = n + 1
  else:
    print(results)  
  count_votes(results)  
election()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some minor structure improvements, I would recommend the following:

```
def election():
    results = {}
    number_of_votes = int(input("Number of votes: "))
    for i in range(number_of_votes):
        vote = input("Choose your candidate: ")
        results[vote] = results.get(vote, 0) + 1
    return results


results = election()
print("Results:")
print(results)

# sort based on votes
# note dicts can only be sorted on python 3.6+
sorted_results = dict(sorted(results.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
print("Results (sorted by vote):")
print(sorted_results)

# display the winner and their votes
winner = next(iter(sorted_results))
winner_votes = sorted_results[winner]
print(f"The winner is {winner} with {winner_votes} votes.")
```

Here is an example election to show how the program will behave:

```
Number of votes: 6
Choose your candidate: a
Choose your candidate: a
Choose your candidate: b
Choose your candidate: b
Choose your candidate: b
Choose your candidate: z
Results:
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'z': 1}
Results (sorted by vote):
{'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'z': 1}
The winner is b with 3 votes.

Process finished with exit code 0
```